# Java Pattern Matching - can matched pattern be memorised and used later in the same regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

The program I am writing needs to ensure that it does not have a word or sequence of chars repeated in the input string.
How can I ensure this using java pattern matching? I think this is possible if regex can memorise the patterns it has found. Or may be I am wrong.
But ultimately I want to know if this is possible using java regex.

Ex:
**goneishegone** \\ should return true - "gone" has appeared twice.
       **goneisheyesterday** \\ should return false -  has not repeating words. (minimum length of words that repeat should be 2 or more)

Comment: Is the word you are asking do be duplicated predefined? Or do you want to check if there is any substring with length >= 2 that appears twice?

Comment: Try this regex: `^(\w{2,}).*\1` https://regex101.com/r/S3G2UY/1. The word which is repeated is present in group1 of each match.

Comment: `if (Pattern.compile("(?s)(\\w{2,}).*\\1").matcher(s).find()) { return true;}`

Comment: @Gurman, that answers. Tx. how to do back reference is what I needed to know.

Comment: Did my suggestion help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the words that your regex matches into a HashSet. If the add() Method returns false, the word is already in the Set. So your solultion would look something like the following:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

Boolean return = false;
Set<String> allMatches = new HashSet<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("your regular expression here")
    .matcher(yourStringHere);
while (m.find()) {
  if(!allMatches.add(m.group())){
    return = true;
    break;
}

System.out.println(Boolean.toString(return));
```